# Некорректно отображаются русские символы в phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Русские символы в phpmyadmin отображаются в виде Ñ„Ñ‹Ð²Ð°Ñ„Ð²Ñ‹Ð°Ð° . Ввод и вывод в базу осуществляется из php файла. Данные выводятся на сайте корректно но в phpmyadmin я их прочитать не могу. Что делать?

Comment: Если на сайте всё работает нормально, то проблема либо а) в кодировке ответа от PMA `Content-Type: charset=...` либо б) в кодировке подключения к БД внутри PMA (обратите внимание на переменные PMA)

Comment: Какая стоит кодировка?

Comment: В полях базы данных стоит котировка utf-8_general_ci на сайте utf8 для пущей верности после обращения к базе данных указал
  $database->query("set character_set_client='utf8'");
  $database->query("set character_set_results=’utf8'");
но это не помогло(

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте

В [конфиге](https://pma.nic.ru/doc/html/config.html#basic-settings) PhpMyAdmin:

```
$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation']  = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Скорее всего из PHP Вы сохраняете в другой кодировке, попробуйте [mysqli::set_charset](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php)

[MySQL documentation for charsets](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html)

Comment: Очень слабо разбираюсь в Админе... вы имеете ввиду файл config.inc.php ? если да то куда вставить эту строчку?

Comment: @DmitriyShaydorov в конфиге она уже есть изначально прописано, это кодировка с которой phpMyAdmin работает по-умолчанию. Скорее всего у БД какая-то другая кодировка и нужно сменить ее. Чтоб в следующий раз такой проблемы не было нужно задавать ее в PHP-коде через mysqli::set_charset

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, разобрался помогла вставка строчек сразу после инициализации объекта(для подключения использовалось PDO) 
$database->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$database->execute();